# How can I add an SVG sprite to a TinyMCE button?

Tags: javascript, svg, tinymce, tinymce-4

I've added some custom toolbar options to TinyMCE, and I want to use an SVG sprite for it's icons. By default, TinyMCE only allows either "text", "icon" or "image" for setting the icons. Ideally, there would be a "html" option, in which I could put my SVG code, but there doesnt'seemt to be one.

How can I add an SVG sprite to a TinyMCE button?

---

**svg-sprites.svg**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
    <symbol id="ic_spoiler" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M12,2A9,9 0 0,0 3,11V22L6,19L9,22L12,19L15,22L18,19L21,22V11A9,9 0 0,0 12,2M9,8A2,2 0 0,1 11,10A2,2 0 0,1 9,12A2,2 0 0,1 7,10A2,2 0 0,1 9,8M15,8A2,2 0 0,1 17,10A2,2 0 0,1 15,12A2,2 0 0,1 13,10A2,2 0 0,1 15,8Z" />
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

**editor-plugin.js**

```
// Function to create SVG html
var iconSVG = function(name, size) {        
    return '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="' + size + '" width="' + size + '" class="' + name + '"><use xlink:href="' + siteURL + '/images/svg-sprite.svg#' + name + '" /></svg>';     
}

// Spoiler Button
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.spoiler', {

    init : function(ed, url) {
        ed.addButton('spoiler', {
            /*
            What I want:
            html: iconSVG('ic_spoiler', 20),

            Doesnt work:
            text: iconSVG('ic_spoiler', 20),
            image: iconSVG('ic_spoiler', 20),
            icon: iconSVG('ic_spoiler', 20),
            */
            title : 'Add a Spoiler'
            onclick : function() {
                 ed.selection.setContent('[spoiler]' + ed.selection.getContent() + '[/spoiler]'); 
            }
        });
    },
    createControl : function(n, cm) {
        return null;
    },
});

tinymce.PluginManager.add('spoiler', tinymce.plugins.spoiler);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opted to a fairly simple solution. After rendering TinyMCE, fire a function with `onPostRender` that replaces  tags with my SVG icon.

```
// Spoiler Button
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.spoiler', {

    init : function(ed, url) {
        ed.addButton('spoiler', {
            icon: 'spoiler',
            title : 'Add a Spoiler'
            onClick : function() {
                 ed.selection.setContent('[spoiler]' + ed.selection.getContent() + '[/spoiler]'); 
            },
            onPostRender: function() {
                $('.mce-i-spoiler').replaceWith(iconSVG('ic_spoiler', 20));
            }
        });
    },
    createControl : function(n, cm) {
        return null;
    },
});

tinymce.PluginManager.add('spoiler', tinymce.plugins.spoiler);
```